# SQL Table Relationships with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new to Laravel and have primarily focused most of my development time on Codeigniter in the past as this is what my job involves for the most part.

I'm currently building a client's website and also building a custom CMS (for both experience and particular needs of the client).

Currently I'm stuggling to figure out how to deal with relationships in Laravel/Eloquent as for example, I have a `products` table. Each product can have a `type`. I'm storing these types in a separate table so I've got better control over them in the future when the content starts to build up. All I need is a query to fetch all products with their associated type. In other frameworks, I could simply do this using a query builder to define the columns and joins, however due to the way Eloquent works, I'm struggling to find the way to do this!

Just for a bit of context, in the CMS, there will be a products datatable which will show all products in the system and one of the columns will be `type`, however I want to show the name of the type, not the `id`.

Probably me being stupid so feel free to point out something obvious!

Comment: You can do this in Laravel... For example, `Product::whereHas('types', function($subQuery){ $subQuery->where('name', 'automotive'); })->get();` will return you all products that have a type of `automotive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is "Eager Loading" which is here in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

In their example on the website, you can replace their "Book" with your "Product" and then their "Author" with your "Type" and you will achieve what you are trying to do.

If you want to load the relationships in the views, i.e. using Blade, you would need to do something like the following:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  <div> {{ $product->type->name }} </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  search for ***`with()`*** function it will be useful in this :
 in your example you need to relate `product` model  with `type` model so in product you will add

```
`public function type()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Type::class);
    }`
```

and in  type add

```
public function Product()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

and your query will be

```
$result=Product::with("type")->get();
```

this will return the related type row with each related product row as 
[this example get user with profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZkFF.png)

and you can get type  name for each product row from

```
foreach($result as $res){
    $type_name=$res->type->name;
  }
```